# What is (are) a decent html-template/layout libraries nowadays?

Tags: html, haskell

I have a Servant application to which I want to add some html pages having a shared master/layout page. What html-template library should I use for creating it? I've seen a few but haven't found one which was:

1. more or less up to date
2. used the external html files rather than describing an html layout in haskell code. This means, I don't want to use something like this

   ```
    getHomeR = defaultLayout
       [whamlet|
           <h1>Welcome to the homepage
           <p>
               Feel free to visit the #
               <a href=@{SubsiteR SubHomeR}>subsite
               \ as well.
       |]
   ```
3. could be plugged in to my Servant application easily. But not only to a Servant app, later I might have web apps in other frameworks so I want to use that library with those as well.

Comment: You can use external files using Hamlet. I'm not so sure about Lucid.

Comment: @Sibi, in Hamlet I've seen the opposite only. How, do you have any link?

Comment: I have added up an working example in the answer. I would also recommend you to go through this chapter: http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates

Comment: @Sibi, thanks, but where is the thing I actually need -- the master layout html page and the html pages inherited from it and all in the external html files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hamlet supports using external html template files. An example working code with Servant:

```
data Person = Person { firstName :: String, lastName :: String }
            deriving (Show, Eq, Generic)

instance ToJSON Person

instance ToMarkup [Person] where
  toMarkup persons = showPersons persons

  preEscapedToMarkup p = showPersons p

people :: [Person]
people =
  [ Person "Isaac"  "Newton"
  , Person "Albert" "Einstein"
  ]

showPersons :: [Person] -> Html
showPersons p = $(shamletFile "person.hamlet")

type PersonAPI = "persons" :> Get '[HTML] [Person]

-- HTML serialization of a list of persons

personAPI :: Proxy PersonAPI
personAPI = Proxy

server :: Server PersonAPI
server = return people

app :: Application
app = serve personAPI server

serveApp :: IO ()
serveApp = run 8081 app
```

Note the function `shamletFile`. Code in the template file `person.hamlet`:

```
<body>
    <p>Profile List page
     $forall person <- p
      <h1>#{firstName person}
```

Entire code with full imports and ghc extensions [here](http://lpaste.net/160169).

Comment: thanks. what's the "$" in `$(shamletFile "person.hamlet")`? in it a standard  haskell function?

Comment: ok. by template I mean "master layout".  That is, I'd have a master-template layout where it describes an html layout with a header and footer and a stub for the content. And all other html pages would use and insert their own content while sharing the header and footer. How can I do that? Does Hamlet support that?

Comment: @Jushiti See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596601/using-licius-hamlet-julius-in-servant

Comment: that shows how to define the html layout in haskell code which isn't what I'm looking for as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Jushiti To answer your question: Yes, Hamlet does support that.That can be done using the embedding feature available in Hamlet. I recommend you to go through the book link mentioned above.

Comment: please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734692/how-to-show-a-hamlet-template-without-a-model-or-only-pure-html